# colormgr get-devices do not return all display

Tags: 16.04, xrandr, colors, color-management

I have a problem about 'colormgr'

I want to change color profile of all display
but, I am not able to get a device from 'colormgr get-device'

I use
OS      : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

GPU     : Radeon pro WX5100 (DP x4)

Display : DP-0 (Blackmagic HDMI-SDI mini converter)
        : DP-1 (Blackmagic HDMI-SDI mini converter)
        : DP-2 (LG Monitor)
        : DP-3 (HDMI splitter)

when I typed

```
    ~$ colormgr get-devices

_____________________________________________________________________________
Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_BMD_HDMI_1_meere_1000
Owner:         meere
Created:       June 24 2019, 11:38:45 PM
Modified:      June 24 2019, 11:38:45 PM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         BMD HDMI
Vendor:        unknown
Serial:        1
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colorspace:    rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-BMD HDMI-1
Profile 1:     icc-c8c5f4b9fac7538ebb0309dc1b906c0c
               /home/meere/.local/share/icc/BMD HDMI #1 2019-01-11 14-48 2.2 F-S XYZLUT+MTX.icc
Profile 2:     icc-cd822cc0c0a64abcc6b21fccd7830978
               /home/meere/.local/share/icc/BMD HDMI #1 2019-01-03 15-15 2.2 F-S XYZLUT+MTX.icc
Profile 3:     icc-bc09d44d73f1a54bfe7c724495e21df0
               /home/meere/.local/share/icc/edid-f3346cd36a2ab7ac381fdb195361a542.icc
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=DisplayPort-0
Metadata:      OutputPriority=primary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=f3346cd36a2ab7ac381fdb195361a542

Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_LG_Electronics_E2251_212NDEZCA340_meere_1000
Owner:         meere
Created:       June 24 2019, 11:38:45 PM
Modified:      June 24 2019, 11:38:45 PM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         E2251
Vendor:        LG Electronics
Serial:        212NDEZCA340
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colorspace:    rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-LG Electronics-E2251-212NDEZCA340
Profile 1:     icc-cd822cc0c0a64abcc6b21fccd7830978
               /home/meere/.local/share/icc/BMD HDMI #1 2019-01-03 15-15 2.2 F-S XYZLUT+MTX.icc
Profile 2:     icc-c8c5f4b9fac7538ebb0309dc1b906c0c
               /home/meere/.local/share/icc/BMD HDMI #1 2019-01-11 14-48 2.2 F-S XYZLUT+MTX.icc
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=DisplayPort-2
Metadata:      OutputPriority=secondary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=335c08ed8c4709a2585b92301b9dafa3

Object Path:   /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/xrandr_SAMSUNG_1_meere_1000
Owner:         meere
Created:       June 24 2019, 11:38:45 PM
Modified:      June 24 2019, 11:38:45 PM
Type:          display
Enabled:       Yes
Embedded:      No
Model:         SAMSUNG
Vendor:        unknown
Serial:        1
Seat:          seat0
Scope:         temp
Colorspace:    rgb
Device ID:     xrandr-SAMSUNG-1
Profile 1:     icc-d3827a14d8a99568eae083e1278a842c
               /home/meere/.local/share/icc/edid-015843aba433b2b750739af094616e7c.icc
Metadata:      XRANDR_name=DisplayPort-3
Metadata:      OutputPriority=secondary
Metadata:      OwnerCmdline=/usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon 
Metadata:      OutputEdidMd5=015843aba433b2b750739af094616e7c
```

---

Only 3 ports are shown (except DP-1)

and when I typed

```
    ~$ xrandr --prop

_____________________________________________________________________________
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384

DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff002301000001000000
        0a190103804728960adaffa3584aa229
        17494b00000001010101010101010101
        010101010101011d8018711c1620582c
        2500c48e2100009e011d007251d01e20
        6e285500c48e2100001e000000fc0042
        4d442048444d490a20202020000000fd
        00173c1f440f000a20202020202001c1
        020321774d858487949396a0a1a29f90
        0312230f040783ff000066030c000000
        008c0aa01451f01600267c4300138e21
        000098011d80d0721c1620102c2580c4
        8e2100009e011d00bc52d01e20b82855
        40c48e2100001e8c0aa0205120181018
        7e2300138e21000098011d803e73382d
        407e2c4580c48e2100001e0000000034
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
DisplayPort-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff002301000001000000
        0a190103804728960adaffa3584aa229
        17494b00000001010101010101010101
        010101010101011d8018711c1620582c
        2500c48e2100009e011d007251d01e20
        6e285500c48e2100001e000000fc0042
        4d442048444d490a20202020000000fd
        00173c1f440f000a20202020202001c1
        020321774d858487949396a0a1a29f90
        0312230f040783ff000066030c000000
        008c0aa01451f01600267c4300138e21
        000098011d80d0721c1620102c2580c4
        8e2100009e011d00bc52d01e20b82855
        40c48e2100001e8c0aa0205120181018
        7e2300138e21000098011d803e73382d
        407e2c4580c48e2100001e0000000034
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
DisplayPort-2 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff001e6d6e5824620600
        0c16010380301b78ea40a5a4554ea026
        115054a76b80714f81c0810081809500
        9040a9c0b300023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e000000fd00384b1e
        530f000a202020202020000000fc0045
        323235310a20202020202020000000ff
        003231324e44455a43413334300a0025
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-3 connected 1920x1080+5760+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000ae09b0601000000
        33130103806639780aee95a3544c9926
        0f5054ffff80714f8100814081809500
        950fb300a940023a801871382d40582c
        4500a05a0000001e662150b051001b30
        40703600a05a0000001e000000fd0018
        4b1a5117000a202020202020000000fc
        0053414d53554e470a202020202001a4
        02031ff14aa284138514031220212223
        0907078301000067030c003000802d02
        3a80d072382d40102c4580a05a000000
        1e011d00bc52d01e20b8285540a05a00
        00001e011d80d0721c1620102c2580a0
        5a0000009e0000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000018
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       87.85    70.08  

_____________________________________________________________________________
```

I catched both blackmagic converter have same EDID .
is it the reason ?

I want to control all display's color

if I changed color profile(BMD HDMI), DP-0 was changed but DP-1 wasn't.

How can I control DP-1's color setting ?

Please let me know .
Thank you

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the BlackMagic converters. Didyou find a solution?